# Как создать экземпляр нужного типа данных в Go

Tags: golang, рефлексия

У меня есть функция

```
func doSome(v interface{}) {

}
```

И мне надо чтобы передав туда указатель на массив структур, она заполнила его именно тем типом структур, которые я передал

```
type Color struct {
}
type Brush struct {
}

var c []Color
doSome(&c) // после с - массив из трех Color

var b []Brush
doSome(&b) // после b - массив из трех Brush
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас не массивы, а слайсы. В го это два разных понятия.

Во-вторых, можно сделать то, что вам нужно с помощью [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/):

```
func doSome(v interface{}) {
    val := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    typ := val.Type().Elem()
    sl := reflect.MakeSlice(typ, 3, 3)
    val.Elem().Set(sl)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/LhTKOZ9fix.

Однако, это будет медленнее и опаснее, чем простой `make([]Brush, 3)`